# Testing Asp.net core; Web api calling for more than 1 million records from database

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core

I am testing very simple ASP.NET Core project with Entity Framework Core connected to a SQL Server database. I created a controller with `GET` method that returns JSON to api call and I filled up database exponentially to 1 million rows. I understand that I should serve only a certain amount of data with query parameter so that my api can handle heavy load.

1. What is the limitation to load that huge json file?
2. I want to generate the report for this amount of data. Let's say it's iot data, sensors data like temperature, pressure, and humidity. What is the right approach to generate report for this kind of data?
3. Can I schedule the task to generate report in ASP.NET Core? Let's say we have node-cron and agenda in nodejs and simple to follow example. So, it's really easy to implement.

For side note, I am still newbie learning how to use dotnet core.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you need help? The limit to a large JSON file is your system resources and the user's patience while it transmits. As for your other questions: sure it's possible. But explaining *how* will take a book or a bunch of good tutorials.

Comment: Actually, it's called seeding in most of the examples. I found that I can directly inject dummy data from controllers, repositories, services, or inject my own class like "services.AddTransient<Seed>();" or similar. I found that it's personal choice. Another thing I found when I generate random rows and push to table, they never follow sequence. As in when I generate A01 to A60, B01 to B60,..., Z01 to Z60. They are inserted quite randomly and not in order.